# How do I update UITableViewCell background color when changing themes?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm implementing dark and black themes in my app using UIAppearance, everything is working well apart from in the tableview I am using control the active theme.

I'm Implementing themes and the switching method is based on this [tutorial:](https://www.raywenderlich.com/652-uiappearance-tutorial-getting-started)

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AtV8.jpg)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Z1TP.jpg)

[Screen recording](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VevtG.jpg)

I've tried calling tableView.reloadData() & setNeedsDisplay on the selected cell in the tableView didSelectRowAt function.

Code I am using the apply the theme is:

Theme.current.apply()

```
    let windows = UIApplication.shared.windows
    for window in windows {
        for view in window.subviews {
            view.removeFromSuperview()
            window.addSubview(view)
        }
    }
```

When applying the new theme the background of the selected cell animated back to the previous themes color once deselectRow completes.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: have you  tried having a .clear cell background color? So it will take the one from the view controller?

Comment: Yes, tried that - same result.

Answer (score -1):

Found the solution to this, setting the Cell background colour to clear resolved the issue.